# Why source code of some website looks messy when I use view page source from browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, frontend

I'm new to web development and when I come a cross a new website I view its source from the browser and try to learn how the site is structured and all. But when I view the source code of some websites, it looks really messy and difficult to learn. I want to know why source code looks like that and if it is for some security purposes, I just want to know what the tools out there that we can turn our source code into that messy unreadable code when we go for production.

You can see the below images to get what I mean.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools to inspect the source in a well structured, readable way. If you just "view source" you'll be seeing the results of caching, templating, minification, and perhaps general poor formatting, all of which lead to hard-to-follow HTML. Here's info on [Chrome's developer tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/), but a similar interface exists in Safari, Firefox, and Edge.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking at there is a process known as [**minification**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)). Many common front-end web development tools such as Bower or Grunt will allow you to compress your files down to the minimum possible code required to have the same output.

Generally this is not done for security purposes, but rather *performance* purposes. Fewer lines leads to fewer bytes in the file, which leads to a faster load for site visitors (less data over the wire).

There's only so much you can do with HTML and CSS, but most tools will be able to minify JavaScript to an extent where it becomes almost unreadable; variable names will be transformed into single letters, and sometimes code will be completely rewritten / optimised.

Keep in mind that front-end copy is **always** visible to the end-user, so you **cannot** completely prevent an end-user from decompiling what you're doing with JavaScript, but if there is proprietary code in play, many companies also like to make it **difficult** for visitors to decompile their client-side code. This is a process known as [**obfsucation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)), and applies similar logic; variable names will be changed, logic will be changed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to **minification**.

Minification is a way of removing unnecessary data without affecting how the code is processed by the browser - e.g. code comments and formatting, removing unused code, using shorter variable and function names, and so on.

That's why the code ends up looking unreadable.

You too can minify your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript resources:

```
To minify HTML, try [HTMLMinifier](http://kangax.github.io/html-minifier/)
To minify CSS, try [CSSNano](https://cssnano.co/)
To minify JavaScript, try [JScompress](https://jscompress.com/)
```

Answer (score 0):

The source code will be minified, thats why its so clumsy while seeing. Minified means eliminating the brackets, spaces, semi-colons.

Frankly speaking, you cant anything from viewing the source code of that website, as you are new to web development. Best way to learn the basics is to get your hands dirty from w3schools (thorough your knowledge from here). Then try to use browser developer tools to understand about the website layout.